# mysqld unknown option '--ndbcluster'

Tags: mysql, macos

I cannot get MySQL to start.  It was running for months on my machine, then my machine crashed and it will not restart.  In the log file I get the following error: 
[ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--ndbcluster'

From what I have read, '--ndbcluster' is an option for running your db in clustered mode.  I am not  running in clustered mode, and I have not attempted to do so.

I am running MySQL 5.6.15 on OS X 10.8.3.

I deleted the MySQL install directory: /usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64, then reinstalled and I get the same error.

Is there some ENV variable that is causing nbcluster to be set?

Update: I installed MySQL Admin during the time between I started MySQL and the machine reset, as well as the MySQL Java libs.

Update: Based on [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?117,227899,227899#msg-227899) there is a my.cnf somewhere (/etc/my.cnf on my Mac) that has those options. The my.cnf file on my machine is full of options about running in cluster mode including the option ndbcluster.

Answer (score 0):

Removing /etc/my.conf and re-installing worked.
After I re-installed MySQL /etc/my.conf was not set.